# How to scale only certain objects LOVE2D

Tags: lua, love2d

This is a problem for the Lua LOVE2D framework.

Whenever I try to set propreties to objects such as color or scaling , it ends up affecting every object in the scene.

For example,

```
    for i,enemy  in ipairs(enemies) do 
    love.graphics.scale(0.2,0.2)
   love.graphics.draw(enemyImg,enemy.x,enemy.y)

   end
```

This scales down not only the enemy object but also all the other objects, anyone know any fix to this?

Comment: I fixed it! I found out the error , I had the scale function twice. I only needed it once which was above everything in the draw functions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in your case would be to make use of the optional parameters to draw.

```
 for _, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
    love.graphics.draw(enemyImg, enemy.x, enemy.y, 0, --rotation
           enemy.scale)
 end
```

that way the scale is unique to each enemy.

Answer (score 0):

As rpattiso noted in their answer, [`love.graphics.draw`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw) excepts two optional parameters `sx` and `sy` that set a specific object's scale factors.

The entire function parameters are:

```
love.graphics.draw(drawable, x, y, r, sx, sy, ox, oy, kx, ky)
```

`r` is the object's rotation, so if you aren't rotating your object just set it to `0`.

As for color, love2d will use the last [`setColor`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor) for drawing. So you would need to change the color for each object that needs a new color.